# How can I get value from user input and show it in another page when I click a button?

Tags: reactjs

User will have to input in the discount after. When they click checkout, it will leads to the other page and will show the input result.

This is the first page where the user input the discount:

[image]

This is the second page:

[image]

What and how should I pass to the parents from Component Page1 to be able to be used in Page 2?

Comment: Please add some code for a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in 2 ways.

1.(Recommend) If using any library/framework store the discounts of n products in to an object and pass that object as a prop to the next page rendering component then by accessing those values show them to the user

```js
const [discounts,setDiscounts]=useState({})
//on enter of discount
 onEnter(setDiscounts({...discount,ItemName:discountEntered}))
```

2.Store all of those in localStorage and retrieve them in next page